# Optional errors Swift 1.2 to 2.0

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to convert Swift 1.2 to 2.0 but I am having problems assign tablviewCell form dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:

```
var cell:UITableViewCell? = tableview!.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifier as String) as? UITableViewCell;

if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: identifier as String)
    cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
}
```

Error:

> Downcast form UITableViewCell to UITableViewcell only unwraps
>   optionals, did you mean to use '!'?

I belive func dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier does not return optional so I have tried :

```
var cell:UITableViewCell = tableview.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifier as String)     
if (cell == nil){
    ...
```

And I get two errors:

> value of optional type tableview not unwrapped, did you mean to use!
>   Binary operator can not be applied to operands of type UITableViewCEll
>   and Niliretalconversion.

Any input appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` returns a `UITableViewCell?`. You're attempting to cast it to a non-optional(`as? UITableViewCell`) but then assign that back to an optional (`cell:UITableViewCell?`). You don't get any information from this extra work and could have used a simpler equivalent expression. Your initial warnings seem to be a result of that confusing ignored cast.

```
var cell:UITableViewCell? = tableview!.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifier as String)
```

We know the type of `cell` here since it matches the return type from `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` so we could write:

```
var cell = tableview!.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifier as String)
```

I can't tell what the type of `identifier` is but that `as` suggests is can always be successfully cast to a `String` so you can probably further simplify to:

```
var cell = tableview!.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifier)
```

This entire conditional can probably be further simplified with an `if let` or `guard` assignment but it's hard to say for sure without knowing the larger context in which it is called.

Answer (score 1):

If you sure, that the casting is correct, then you can do this:

```
var cell:UITableViewCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifer as String) as UITableViewCell!;

        if (cell == nil)
        {
            cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: identifer as String)
            cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        }
```

If you are not sure that the casting will be absolutely not nil, you can do this:

```
var cell:UITableViewCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifer as String) as? UITableViewCell?;
```

Notice, you shouldn't identify explicitly the type of `cell` parameter in this case, because Swift will infer it automatically.

Comment: Thanks, still get a  bit confused with  optionals!